Bypass JWT Authentication with NginX so i can use Authentik Reverse Proxy Authentication
With NginX Proxy Manager I am trying to bypass JWT authentication. In this example I will use NginX Proxy Manager web GUI as it users JWT Authentication.
From my device I can successfully fetch a new token (valid for a day or less) from remote server but sadly longlive tokens are no longer supported:
curl 'http://localhost:81/api/tokens' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
  --data-raw '{"identity":"[Your Email]","secret":"[Your Secret]"}' \
  --compressed

I tried creating a JWT token of the values {"identity":"[Your Email]","secret":"[Your Secret]"} and pass them in NginX as follows
proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer jwt-token";
proxy_pass_header Authorization;

Sadly that was unsuccessful. Is there a method to use NginX to fetch a JWT token and authenticate?

I just learned that the {"identity":"[Your Email]","secret":"[Your Secret]"} should be the body of the request in order to get a respond.

here I used NPM Web UI as an example since it uses JWT Authentication. This can be applied on most Web Aplications that use similar Authentication.
In this case i created A group with special permition to log into several services but you can do this on user level. In the group/user add the following Attributes with the correct user/pass. Leave the Token as Null
nginx_password: pass
nginx_username: user
additionalHeaders:
  X-Nginx-Token: null

Under Property Mappings create a new Scoop Maping. Name is NginX Token and Scoop Name must be ak_proxy otherwise NginX cannot call the apropeate headers. Adjust the Expression from group_attributes() to attributes for user based authentication.
The Expression should be as following:
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

nginxuser = request.user.group_attributes().get("nginx_username", "")
nginxpass = request.user.group_attributes().get("nginx_password", "")

base_url = "http://nginx:81"
end_point = "/api/tokens"
json_data = {'identity': nginxuser,'secret': nginxpass}
postdata = json.dumps(json_data).encode()
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
httprequest = Request(base_url + end_point, data=postdata, method="POST", headers=headers)

with urlopen(httprequest) as response:
     responddata = json.loads(response.read().decode())
return {
    "ak_proxy": {
        "user_attributes": {
            "additionalHeaders": {
                "X-Nginx-Token": responddata['token']
            }
        }
    }
}

The Expression will fetch a new Autherization Token which can be accessed through the X-Nginx-Token Header.
Create a Proxy Provider and make sure the Scoop we just created is included.
In NPM I added this configuration. Dnt forget to change the Authentik Server address
proxy_buffers 8 16k;
proxy_buffer_size 32k;

# Make sure not to redirect traffic to a port 4443
port_in_redirect off;

location / {
    proxy_pass          $forward_scheme://$server:$port;

    ##############################
    # authentik-specific config
    ##############################
    auth_request     /outpost.goauthentik.io/auth/nginx;
    error_page       401 = u/goauthentik_proxy_signin;
    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    add_header       Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

    # Here we call the Header we created and use the Token that Authentik fetched for us
    auth_request_set $authentik_auth $upstream_http_x_nginx_token;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer ${authentik_auth}";
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
}

# all requests to /outpost.goauthentik.io must be accessible without authentication
location /outpost.goauthentik.io {
    # When using the embedded outpost, use:
    proxy_pass              https://authentik-server:9443/outpost.goauthentik.io;

    # Note: ensure the Host header matches your external authentik URL:
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;

    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
    add_header              Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
    auth_request_set        $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
}

# Special location for when the /auth endpoint returns a 401,
# redirect to the /start URL which initiates SSO
location u/goauthentik_proxy_signin {
    internal;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
    return 302 /outpost.goauthentik.io/start?rd=$request_uri;
    # For domain level, use the below error_page to redirect to your authentik server with the full redirect path
    # return 302 https://authentik.company/outpost.goauthentik.io/start?rd=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
}

That should be it. I tried it and it works perfectly
